# Does index occupy disk memory for rows for which index expression is NULL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's assume that I have following `pg_trgm` index on `mydata JSONB` column:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mydata JSONB);
CREATE INDEX trgm_index_1 ON mytable
USING gin ((mydata#>>'{myfield}') gin_trgm_ops);
```

And let's assume that I will insert following data into `mytable`:

```
500k rows with mydata = { "myfield": "some_text" }
500k rows with mydata = { "another_field": "some_text" }
```

So `1M` rows in total, but half of them contains value that is used in index expression (`mydata#>>'{myfield}'`). Does it mean that index will use ~50% less memory on disk than it would use if all of rows contained `myfield` json field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simply try it!

I've created the table from your question, then did the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT json_object(ARRAY['myfield', i::text || 'bla'])::jsonb 
FROM generate_series (1, 100000) t(i);

\di+ trgm_index_1

 Schema │     Name     │ Type  │ Owner  │  Table  │ Size  │ Description 
────────┼──────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────────
 test   │ trgm_index_1 │ index │ avaczi │ mytable │ 19 MB │
```

So far, we have only rows where `myfield` is present.  Let's now add some other rows, too:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT json_object(ARRAY['other_field', i::text || 'bla'])::jsonb 
FROM generate_series (100001, 200000) t(i);
```

After this, the reported index size has changed to 22 MB, meaning that the new rows are also accounted for.  If you want to exclude them, you have to create a partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_index_partial ON mytable
USING gin ((mydata#>>'{myfield}') gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE mydata ? 'myfield';
```

The size of this one is initially the same (19 MB) as the non-partial index, but after adding the second group of rows, **it does not change**:

```
\di+ trgm_index_*

 Schema │        Name        │ Type  │ Owner  │  Table  │ Size  │ Description 
────────┼────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────────
 test   │ trgm_index_1       │ index │ avaczi │ mytable │ 22 MB │ 
 test   │ trgm_index_partial │ index │ avaczi │ mytable │ 19 MB │
```